# Using UpdateListItems for multiple items?

Tags: 2010, jquery, caml-query, spservices

I would like to use UpdateListItems or something similar to allow my users to pass in some variable (e.g., a name) so I can use a caml query to find all items where SomeUserField = 'John B Smith' and replace that field with the value that they enter.

I see here: http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=UpdateListItems
that there is an "ID" parameter which makes it seem like I can only use this to update a single item.

Is it possible to have this change happen for all items where that query is true using only JavaScript/jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do a batch update query where the IDs are not known, you need to use this action: [SPUpdateMultipleListItems](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=%24%28%29.SPServices.SPUpdateMultipleListItems).

Example from the documentation:

```
$().SPServices.SPUpdateMultipleListItems({
  listName: "States",
  CAMLQuery: "<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Status'/><Value Type='Text'>Active</Value></Eq></Where></Query>",
  valuepairs: [["Status", "Inactive"]]
});
```